# Why does my Rake task not work properly on the first run?

Tags: ruby, rake, rake-task, rakefile

**Background**

I have a rake task called `prepare` to update my `hosts.txt` file based on an environment variable I set i.e: `rake spec environment=test`

The `mule` task reads from the `hosts` variable in order to run the rspec tests.

**Rakefile**

```
require 'rake'
require 'rspec/core/rake_task'

hosts = IO.readlines('./hosts.txt').sort!


task :spec => 'spec:prepare'
task :spec => 'spec:mule_esb'

namespace :spec do

    task :prepare do
        sh ("cd ../capistrano && cap OVS_#{ENV['environment']} admin:trigger_serverspec_hosts")
    end

    task :mule_esb => hosts
        hosts.each do |host|
        begin
        desc "Run serverspec on #{host}"
        RSpec::Core::RakeTask.new(host) do |t|
            ENV['TARGET_HOST'] = host
            puts "\u2630 #{host.upcase}"
            # Write to file and stdout in documentation format
            t.rspec_opts = '--out rspec_results.txt --format documentation'
            t.pattern = "spec/mule_esb/*_spec.rb"
            t.verbose = false
            # Stop serverspec from early termination if it fails on a single host
            # Exit code will always be zero
            t.fail_on_error = false
        end
        rescue 
    end
  end
end
```

As you can see  I have ordered the tasks as follows:

```
task :spec => 'spec:prepare'
task :spec => 'spec:mule_esb'
```

**Observation**

1. Command: `rake spec environment=test`

   - `prepare` task runs successfully and updates the `hosts.txt` file
     but the `mule_esb` task runs from hosts set as part of the
     previous run (when environment was `staging`)
   - If I run it again without any changes it successfully runs it on the `test` environment hosts
2. Running the tasks individually works as expected

   - `rake spec spec:prepare` and then `rake spec:mule_esb`

I'm stumped as to why this is happening. I'm not all that familiar with Rake - Can someone explain this behaviour?

Comment: Try: `environment=test rake spec`. Set Env variable before task.

Comment: @SergiiK: Unfortunately that didn't work either.

Answer (score 0):

Do this

namespace :spec do

```
task prepare: :environment do

    sh ("cd ../capistrano && cap OVS_#{ENV['environment']} proteus:trigger_serverspec_hosts")

end
```

end

specify environment with task name.

Comment: That doesn't make sense to me but I tried it anyway and got the following error `rake aborted!
Don't know how to build task 'environment'

Tasks: TOP => spec => spec:prepare`